# Actors and mailboxes - Who delivers the message?

Tags: akka, actor

I have a question on the messages going to the mailbox of an actor. I am aware that the actor has a mailbox but not as a part of it. Mailbox is provided by the actor system.

The Question:

I have an actor myAct running on thread with id 10. myAct then ! a message to another actor yourAct. Is it the responsibility of thread 10 to take the message to the mailbox of yourAct or does ActorSystem assign another thread to deliver the message to the mail box.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, to remove all potential misleading facts: there is no thread assigned as responsible for a specific actor. Hence, when you say `I have an actor myAct running on thread with id 10` - this might be right, but only at that particular time.

Snippet from the Akka official documentation:

> Behind the scenes Akka will run sets of actors on sets of real
>   threads, where typically many actors share one thread, and subsequent
>   invocations of one actor may end up being processed on different
>   threads. Akka ensures that this implementation detail does not affect
>   the single-threadedness of handling the actor’s state

Secondly, **message delivery** and **processing** are two different activities within an actor, which are most probably happening on different threads.

When you send a message to an actor, you're only sending it to its ActorRef, which will, then, contact the dispatcher and use it to queue the message onto the targeted actor's mailbox. Hence, the only blocking that occurs from the caller's perspective is the act of enqueueing the message. After that, all of the extra work and processing might be done on a separate thread.

I hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Akka's default executor for [dispatchers](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/dispatchers.html) is a [fork-join-executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) which employs a queue-based `work-stealing` algorithm.  So, I don't think there is any guarantee a given dispatcher will be the sole owner of a certain task throughout the lifecycle of an actor.

This [article](http://www.h-online.com/developer/features/The-fork-join-framework-in-Java-7-1762357.html) describes some details about how the worker threads share work in the fork-join framework.